# OMNeT++ & Veins steady state vehicle density

Tags: omnet++, veins

I want to keep a constant number of cars in my (long) simulation  (OMNeT+Veins). I do not care about mobility that much so i could probably use the Veins in-built function *.manager.numVehicles = 100. The thing is that if i do not specify any(enough) vehicle flows (from SUMO) my simulation terminates instantly (because of no events). So i create some flows (that exit the simulation sooner) and Veins fills up for the cars as they dissappear.

Is there a more elegant way to do this? I'd prefer to just use the numVehicles function since it's easier and the cars move minimally so they remain in the simulation for long.

I need steady-state vehicular density (number of vehicles fixed - even if old ones leave and new ones enter to replace them at the same instant).

Thanks,
Andreas

Answer (score 0):

The autoShutdown parameter can be set to false to instruct the coupling interface to keep going even though there are no more cars in the simulation. See https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4.5/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIScenarioManagerLaunchd.ned#L55

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/71071341/7215379 has a solution. It actually is meant to keep the number of vehicles in simulation constant. You can look into the possibility of reusing it.