# How to limit the time vehicles are in scenario and make vehicles leave automatically?

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I'm implementing some attacks in veins and using Sumo I made a map and added all the 120(120 vehicles but during the simulation totally 30 vehicles must be in the map at the same time) vehicles I need, the problem is that all the vehicles are inserted but not departed at all. I want to have some sort of lifetime for vehicles and each stay for around 15 seconds. I would appreciate if someone help me with this problem.

Bests

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what veins offers here but there is no automated way to tell sumo that a vehicle should leave after a certain amount of time. The only workaround I can think of is to check the time yourself and remove the vehicle with a script. As far as I can tell veins does not implement the remove function for a vehicle but you could set a new route which ends at the current edge using `TraCICommandInterface::Vehicle::getRoadId` and `TraCICommandInterface::Vehicle::newRoute`.

Comment: Thanks, as I'm new to Sumo and everything, I don't know how to do it, is there any helpful documentation or example? what about limiting the route a vehicle should take so it takes less time? in this case when we reduce the number of hops does it mean at the end of its route the node leaves?

Comment: I can just give you this link: https://veins.car2x.org/documentation/modules/#traci

Answer (score 1):

One way I could think of would be to use the `TraCICommandInterface::Vehicle::moveTo()` or `TraCICommandInterface::Vehicle::moveToXY()` function in TraCI(We have to define the function in traciCommandInterface.CPP and .h files in veins).You can move the vehicle to a specific location( like the end of your road network ) based on specific conditions( like the 15 seconds time interval that was mentioned above).

Comment: thank you I should try this way too.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.grc.upv.es/Software/oldsw/vacamobil.html

The above link has a solution for your scenario.  The work tries to keep the number of cars a constant value during the simulation. meanNumberOfCars is the parameter to look at.